# Make two networks talk to a third network but not each other?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I would like two computers made to be unable to talk to each other but share a printer only using a Cisco switch.

I'm assuming this would be done with 3 different VLANs but I'm unsure of how to make the two computers talk to the printer but not each other.

Comment: You need Access Control Lists (ACLs). There is plenty of documentation available on how to use ACLs to achieve isolation.

Comment: We need to write ACL in Cisco switch. Layer 2 switches have no routes, vlans are not connected, and cannot access each other. A three-layer switch can have a route. What model is your switch?

Answer (score 0):

**Two situations**

**1. The uplink switch is a Layer 2 switch. Communication between different VLANs requires a route.**

[image]

Router 0 is connected to the switch 24 ports, Switch 1 port is connected to PC1，Switch 2 is connected to PC2，Switch 3 port connection PRINTER.

**The main configuration of the router is as follows:**

interface FastEthernet0/0.1

encapsulation dot1Q 100

ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

ip access-group vlan100 in

!

interface FastEthernet0/0.2

encapsulation dot1Q 200

ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0

ip access-group vlan200 in

!

interface FastEthernet0/0.3

encapsulation dot1Q 300

ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0

**router ospf 100**

**log-adjacency-changes**

**network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0**

**network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0**

**network 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255 area 0**

ip access-list extended vlan100

deny ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255

permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any

ip access-list extended vlan200

deny ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any

**Switch configuration：**

interface FastEthernet0/1

switchport access vlan 100

!

interface FastEthernet0/2

switchport access vlan 200

!

interface FastEthernet0/3

switchport access vlan 300

interface FastEthernet0/24

switchport mode trunk

**2. The switch is a Layer 3 switch with the following topology:**

[image]

Switch 1 port is connected to PC1, Switch 2 is connected to PC2, Switch 3 port connection PRINTER

**Switch configuration：**

interface FastEthernet0/1

switchport access vlan 100

!

interface FastEthernet0/2

switchport access vlan 200

!

interface FastEthernet0/3

switchport access vlan 300

**interface Vlan100**

**ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0**

**ip access-group vlan100 in**

interface Vlan200

ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0

ip access-group vlan200 in

!

interface Vlan300

ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0

**ip access-list extended vlan100**

**deny ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255**

**permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any**

**ip access-list extended vlan200**

**deny ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255**

**permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any**

Comment: Please consider adding to your answer an explanation of the important features of this configuration and how it addresses the OP's question.